# Why is my cat only losing guard hairs?

Tags: cats, health, allergies, hairloss

He is 6yo, domestic short hair. He had "allergies" last summer so the vet told me. He was missing hair on his legs, mostly the front ones. I kept him inside and all his hair grew back. This summer he started scratching again despite Zyrtec and so I kept him inside again, but this time his hairs have not grown back. Additionally, he has lost his guard hairs all over his belly and legs, his paws are fine and his fur is there.

I haven't changed his food or anything else about his routine, except that he's not allowed out anymore, which he hates. I did add a complete oil to his food about a month ago. It's not fleas or mites. It's just weird to me that it's only the guard hairs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Pets :)
Have you tried not giving the oil to see if it changes things?

Comment: Well I started the oil a month ago as the vet suggested and he's been missing hair since the summer. (At least June) and it hasn't gotten any worse since before I started it. He's looked the same since June no progress forwards or backwards.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to experiment a bit with food--something you can control. My cat suffers an unknown obstruction that made her vomit, daily. The vet prescribed Predisolone steroid which I added daily to her wet food (I offer my cats both wet meals and dry chow). After a year of this (at $40/mo), I had occasion to switch out my chow brand and type, and at random I opted for a higher-quality version formulated for senior cats. Bingo! The vomiting ceased, also her coat and overall health visibly improved. Anyway, switching out things I CAN control has become my initial go-to, so what could it hurt you to try? (Note:I decided to switch vets.) I wish you luck.